# CGAffineTransform doesn't work with custom UIView

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, cgaffinetransform

I'm trying to create a custom view class that is a popup with a UICollectionView on it. I've created functions to animate the view in and out, but only the animate out function is actually working.

I'm setting constraints as follows...

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
}

func commonInit(){
    ...
    self.addSubview(collectionView)
    collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.7).isActive = true
    ...
    self.animateIn()
}
```

Then to handle the animation I'm using the following...

```
func animateIn(){
    self.collectionView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: self.collectionView.frame.height)
    self.blurredBackgroundView.alpha = 0      
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.blurredBackgroundView.alpha = 1
        self.collectionView.transform = .identity

    })
}
```

And the animateOut function (which works) is...

```
func animateOut(){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.collectionView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: self.collectionView.frame.height)
        self.blurredBackgroundView.alpha = 0
    }) { (complete) in
        if complete {
            self.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

But the initial CGAfineTransform isn't working so the view is appearing in its final position when it first appears. I'm confused as it's working perfectly for the animateOut function which is called when a button is pressed to close the popup.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I feel like there must be something basic I'm missing.

Thanks

Comment: You posted your animateIn function, but not your animateOut function. You also didn't show where animateOut gets called.

Comment: Where do you call `commonInit`?

Comment: Sorry... I've updated the questions with those details.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to start your animation from an initializer, but by that time, the view isn't a part of view hierarchy. Since it's impossible to animate a view that isn't part of the view hierarchy, the transform is applied immediately. `animateOut` works fine, because when you call it the view is already displayed.

What you need to do is to call your `animateIn` function explicitly after the view has been added to view hierarchy

```
let yourView = YourView(frame: someFrame)
superview.addSubview(yourView)
yourView.animateIn()
```

Comment: I've tried that and it still isn't working. I've also tried to remove animations completely and load the view with the initial tranlateX in place, but that seems to be what's being ignored. I can't set the initial start position for the collection view using CGAffineTransform. But it work for animating it out.